# Applying Color Gradient to Rows in AgGrid Dash Table

Tags: python, plotly, ag-grid, plotly-dash

In the following code, I want to apply a color gradient to the background color of each row based on the combined addition of two columns: 'Raised to Date' and 'Years in Operation' (higher values should result in a deeper shade of color). I want to make sure that this operation is performed in the callback, and the color shading should work based on a specific dropdown segment, not on the overall data.

```
import dash
from dash import dcc, html, Input, Output
import dash_ag_grid as dag
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Example data for the DataFrame 'df'
data = {
    "Company name": ["Company {}".format(i) for i in range(1, n_rows + 1)],
    "Years in Operation": np.random.randint(1, 20, n_rows),
    "Raised to Date": np.random.uniform(1, 100, n_rows).round(2),
    "Product": np.random.choice(["Product A", "Product B", "Product C"], n_rows),
    "Bucket": np.random.choice(["Bucket 1", "Bucket 2", "Bucket 3"], n_rows),
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Initialize the Dash app
app = dash.Dash(__name__)

# Define the layout
app = dash.Dash(__name__)

# Define the layout
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1("Valuation Table"),
    dcc.Dropdown(id='product-dropdown', options=[{'label': 'Product A', 'value': 'Product A'}, {'label': 'Product B', 'value': 'Product B'}], value='Product A'),
    dcc.Dropdown(id='bucket-dropdown', options=[{'label': 'All', 'value': 'All'}, {'label': 'Bucket 1', 'value': 'Bucket 1'}, {'label': 'Bucket 2', 'value': 'Bucket 2'}], value='All'),
    dag.AgGrid(
        id='valuation-table',
        columnDefs=[
            {"headerName": "Company Name", "field": "Company name"},
            {"headerName": "Years in Operation (yr)", "field": "Years in Operation"},
            {"headerName": "Raised to Date ($m)", "field": "Raised to Date"},
            {"headerName": "Product", "field": "Product"},
            {"headerName": "Bucket", "field": "Bucket"},
        ],
        style={'height': '400px', 'width': '100%'},
    ),
    html.Div(id='table-heading')
])

# Callback to update the ag-Grid table
@app.callback(
    [Output('valuation-table', 'rowData'),
     Output('table-heading', 'children')],
    [Input('product-dropdown', 'value'),
     Input('bucket-dropdown', 'value')]
)
def update_table(selected_product, selected_bucket):
    if selected_bucket == 'All':
        filtered_df = df[df['Product'] == selected_product]
    else:
        filtered_df = df[(df['Bucket'] == selected_bucket) & (df['Product'] == selected_product)]

    # Calculate a combined value for color gradient
    filtered_df['Combined Value'] = filtered_df['Raised to Date'] + filtered_df['Years in Operation']
    max_combined_value = filtered_df['Combined Value'].max()

    # Preprocess the DataFrame to include HTML style tags in the cell values
    for col in filtered_df.columns:
        if col != 'Combined Value':
            filtered_df[col] = filtered_df.apply(lambda row: f'<div style="background-color: rgba(0, 123, 255, {row["Combined Value"]/max_combined_value});">{row[col]}</div>', axis=1)

    # Create rowData for ag-Grid
    row_data = filtered_df.to_dict('records')

    return row_data, html.Div(f"Filtered by Product: {selected_product}, Bucket: {selected_bucket}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, port=8573)
```

The problem is  i dont see any color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the HTML you put in the grid is escaped and rendered as text. Another way to achieve this is to apply conditional styles via the grid property `getRowStyle` (see [Styling Rows](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-ag-grid/styling-rows)) :

> `getRowStyle` (dict) The styles to apply for each row individually. Dict
> with the keys:
>
> - `styleConditions` (list of dicts). Each dict has keys:
>
>   - `condition` (string) JavaScript expression that determines whether to apply style.
>   - `style` (dict). The style properties to apply when `condition` is true.

```py
# Callback to update the ag-Grid table
@app.callback(
    [Output('valuation-table', 'rowData'),
     Output('valuation-table', 'getRowStyle'),
     Output('table-heading', 'children')],
    [Input('product-dropdown', 'value'),
     Input('bucket-dropdown', 'value')]
)
def update_table(selected_product, selected_bucket):
    if selected_bucket == 'All':
        filtered_df = df[df['Product'] == selected_product]
    else:
        filtered_df = df[(df['Bucket'] == selected_bucket) & (df['Product'] == selected_product)]

    # Calculate a combined value for color gradient
    filtered_df['Combined Value'] = filtered_df['Raised to Date'] + filtered_df['Years in Operation']
    max_combined_value = filtered_df['Combined Value'].max()

    # Apply conditional row styles according to those combined values
    getRowStyle = {
        'styleConditions': [
            {
                'condition': f'params.data["Combined Value"] == {value}',
                'style': {'backgroundColor': f'rgba(0, 123, 255, {value / max_combined_value}'},
            }
            for value in filtered_df['Combined Value'].unique()
        ]
    }

    # Create rowData for ag-Grid
    row_data = filtered_df.to_dict('records')

    return row_data, getRowStyle, html.Div(f"Filtered by Product: {selected_product}, Bucket: {selected_bucket}")
```